# Return all possible values of a columns while also grouping by values in another column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, databricks

how to group by the value in one column and append all the possible values in another column,

e.g.

```
   Col1, Col2
    ----  ----
    1     a
    2     a
    3     a
    1     b
    2     b
    4     c
```

and how to get below:

```
 Col1,      Col2,   count
    ----    ----   -----
    1,2,3     a     3
    1,2       b     2
    4         c     1
```

Comment: Most databases have some form of string aggregation - if you do as the `sql` tag suggests and TAG yours, we'll know what to recommend.

Comment: You may be able to use STRING_AGG function if your version of SQL Server supports it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a modern version of SQL Server, the following would be all you need:

```
select String_Agg(col1,',') Col1, col2, Count(*) [count]
from t
group by col2;
```